# Find mean from 5th percentile

Tags: r, statistics

I need some guideance with a statistics problem. I have a situation where a know the 5th percentile of a normal distributed continous random variable. I want to compute the average value. The data set and standard deviation are not known.

I want to solve my problem with R, do you have any hints for useful functions or methods?

Thanks, John

Comment: I am afraid that's incomplete knowledge if you only have the 5th percentile yet two unknown variables (mean and std).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal distribution is described by mean and deviation (two values), and you know 5th percentile only (one value). It's necessary to have some additional value (e.g. 10th percentile) to calculate mean and deviation.

Comment: So if I predict, lets say the 10th percentile I'm on my way?

Comment: @johnhenning If you know the 5th & 10th percentile, you can calculate your unknowns.   However, from which information will you be predicting the 10th?

Comment: Yes, in this case you have got simple linear system: p5 = mean + sd * qnorm(5/100), p10 = mean + sd * qnorm(10/100)